# CoreData join entities for sorting

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, core-data, entity

I have a problem sorting "join" entities with CoreData.
I've made a model like this:
[image]

The logic is like this: Entity A has a list of items. User can selects one or more items from A and put them in entity C. That works fine. But the results set becomes unsorted (logically). So I've implemented a "join" entity B like this:

[image]

So now the results can be sorted by the field date in entity B which is kind a "join" between entity A and B.

But here I get confused. When I insert new items into B, do I need to add them also to the C and A or they are inserted automatically with relations?

**EDIT** - solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call one of the CoreData-generated `addXXXItemsObject` methods, or set a relation property like `b.c = myCInstance;`, that will set up exactly *one* relation for you.

So you can set up your B object in a number of different ways. First set up the `c <--> b` relation:

```
b.c = instanceOfC;
// or
[c addBItemsObject:b];
```

And then the `b <--> a` relation:

```
b.a = instanceOfA;
// or
[a addBItemsObject:b];
```

The simplest is probably just to use the first version for each:

```
    b.c = instanceOfC;
    b.a = instanceOfA;
```

Also, looking at your screenshot, it looks like you need to make some ends of your relationships as to-many.

**EDIT**: edited this about 5 times to make it more coherant.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. But I have another concern: Till now I've gotten all the item of C from A like that: [C.a allObjects]. But how can I do that now?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just grab all the B items, and when iterating you can get the corresponding C via `b.c`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a good idea to iterate over all items. I would like to have only those one for exact one C... ?